# Custom prompt doesn't work on Mac's terminal

Tags: bash, prompt, .bash-profile

I like to use a custom prompt (current path in blue) on my unix machine:

```
export PS1='\[\e[0;34m\]\w \$\[\e[m\] '
```

But when I try to use it on Mac's terminal it doesn't work: it fails to detect the end of the prompt and overwrites the prompt when I type commands. This also happens when I'm inputting a long command where it wraps over the same line instead of starting a new line.

I don't understand why this is the case since I use bash on both machines. Any suggestions on how to remedy this?

Comment: Please check the output of `echo $PS1` to ensure the actual value being used for `PS1`. The line in question is correct and should work on you Mac.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me in both Terminal and iTerm2.  Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are asking?

[image: screenshot of prompt being applied with long command and line wrapping]